# How to get the client_id, client_secret and user_agent parameters from Reddit with discord.py

Tags: parameters, discord.py, reddit, praw, redditkit

I'm creating a Discord.py bot and what I want it to do is add a `!meme` command on which it pulls a random meme from the r/memes subreddit. I have found some code on Stack Overflow as to how to do that. My problem is that I need 3 parameters, `client_id`, `client_secret` and `user_agent`, which I don't know how to get. Here's the code I found:

```py
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='CLIENT_ID HERE',
                     client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET HERE',
                     user_agent='USER_AGENT HERE')

@bot.command()
async def meme():
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

    await bot.say(submission.url)
```

Can someone help me get those parameters?

Comment: You need to go [here](https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps) and create an app

Comment: what do I put in as url?

Comment: Anything. I just put in http://127.0.0.1

Comment: done, how do I get the id and stuff now?

Comment: ok, I found the id and the secret but what about the user_agent?

Comment: I believe you can call it whatever you like, I just took the name that I gave the reddit app